# Android ExpandableListView CheckBox Select Only Clicked Checkbox

Tags: android, select, checkbox, expandablelistview

I have a quick question on `ExpandableListViews` and using `CheckBoxes`.  I will show the current code below.  I currently have a `ExpandableListView` with a checkbox in each child row.

These `checkboxes` can be selected and such but the problem is I have many children in my `ExpandableListView`.  So the problem is that when I check on box, it shows that more than one checkbox is selected.  So if I check the first child checkbox it also shows that the 6th or 7th child is also selected.

```
package com.WebGems.MW3CustomClasses;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PrimaryWeapon extends Activity {
    ExpandableListView listPrimaryWeapon;


    //Strike Package ArrayLists

    ArrayList assaultPackage = new ArrayList();




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.primary_weapon);
        listPrimaryWeapon = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String type = extras.getString("type");


        if(type.equals("assault")) {
            showAssaultPackageList();
        }


    }
    private void showAssaultPackageList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        assaultPackage.add("UAV");
        assaultPackage.add("CARE PACKAGE");
        assaultPackage.add("I.M.S.");
        assaultPackage.add("PREDATOR MISSILE");
        assaultPackage.add("SENTRY GUN");
        assaultPackage.add("PRECISION AIRSTRIKE");
        assaultPackage.add("ATTACK HELICOPTER");
        assaultPackage.add("STRAFE RUN");
        assaultPackage.add("AH-6 OVERWATCH");
        assaultPackage.add("REAPER");
        assaultPackage.add("ASSAULT DRONE");
        assaultPackage.add("AC-130");
        assaultPackage.add("PAVE LOW");
        assaultPackage.add("JUGGERNAUT");
        assaultPackage.add("OSPREY GUNNER");



        // Construct Expandable List
        final String NAME = "name";
        final String IMAGE = "image";
        final String DATA = "data";
        final String NUMBER = "number";

        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> headerData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        final HashMap<String, String> group1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        group1.put(NAME, "Assault Package");
        headerData.add( group1 );

        final ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> childData = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>();

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> group1data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        childData.add(group1data);

        int assaultPackageCounter = 0;
        for(int arm = 0; arm < assaultPackage.size(); ++arm) {
            final HashMap<String, Object> assaultPackageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            assaultPackageMap.put(NAME, assaultPackage.get(arm));
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 0) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.uav));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "UAV DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.three));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 1) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.carepackage));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "CARE PACKAGE DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.four));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 2) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ims));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "IMS DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.five));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 3) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.predatormissile));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "PREDATOR MISSILE DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.five));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 4) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sentrygun));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "SENTRY GUN DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.five));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 5) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.precisionairstrike));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "PRECISION AIRSTRIKE DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.six));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 6) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.attackhelicopter));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "ATTACK HELICOPTER DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seven));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 7) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.straferun));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "STRAFE RUN DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nine));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 8) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ahsixoverwatch));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "AH-6 OVERWATCH DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nine));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 9) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.reaper));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "REAPER DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nine));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 10) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.assaultdrone));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "ASSAULT DRONE DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ten));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 11) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.aconethreezero));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "AC-130 DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twelve));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 12) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pavelow));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "PAVE LOW DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twelve));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 13) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.juggernaut));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "JUGGERNAUT DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fifteen));
            }
            if(assaultPackageCounter == 14) {
                assaultPackageMap.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ospreygunner));
                assaultPackageMap.put(DATA, "OSPREY GUNNER DESCRIPTION");
                assaultPackageMap.put(NUMBER, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seventeen));
            }
            assaultPackageCounter++;
            group1data.add(assaultPackageMap);
        }
        assaultPackageCounter = 0;

        // Set up some sample data in both groups
        /*for( int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
            final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put(NAME, "Child " + i );
            //map.put(DATA, "Data " + i);
            map.put(IMAGE, getResources().getDrawable((i%3==0? R.drawable.arrowright : R.drawable.arrowdown)));
            ( i%2==0 ? group1data : group2data ).add(map);
        }*/

        listPrimaryWeapon.setAdapter( new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                headerData,
                R.layout.group_row,
                new String[] { NAME, DATA },    // the names of the data
                new int[] { R.id.groupname },   // the text field to populate with the field data
                childData,
                0,
                null,
                new int[] {}
            ) {
                @Override
                public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    final View v = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);

                    // Populate your custom view here
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText( (String) ((Map<String,Object>)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(NAME) );
                    ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText( (String) ((Map<String,Object>)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(DATA) );
                    ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable( (Drawable) ((Map<String,Object>)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(IMAGE) );
                    ((ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageDrawable( (Drawable) ((Map<String,Object>)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition)).get(NUMBER) );
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.checkBox1 );
                    cb.setClickable(false);
                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View newChildView(boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
                     return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.strikepackagelayout, null, false);
                }
            }
        );
        ExpandableListView list = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        list.setChoiceMode(ExpandableListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        list.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener(){
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)v.findViewById( R.id.checkBox1 );
                if(cb != null){
                    cb.toggle();
                }
                Log.d("type", "Group: " + groupPosition + ", Child: " + childPosition);
                System.out.println("Group:"+groupPosition+", Child: "+childPosition);
                return true;
            }
        });
        listPrimaryWeapon.expandGroup(0);




    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Expandable list view Recycle the view each time you move. so you need to save the state of each views.

1> set different id for each checkbox. something like that
      checkBox.setId(groupPosition + 1);

2> add the selected checkbox id to a hash map object like

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCheckedChanged(if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                                            mapViewState.put(checkBox.getId(),
                                                    checkBoxSelected);
                                        } else {
                                            mapViewState.remove(checkBox
                                                    .getId());
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
```

and then load the status of the check box from HashMap, or iterate it to get the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of using recycling View for use in ExpandableListView. As you can see there is a field "View convertView" which contains View that will be recycled with SAME ID as View that already exists on a screen. So when you look for `v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)` there can be more than one "v" element with given ID - that makes Android select more than one CheckBox. The only way to override it (that I know for now) is to remove "covertView" from `super.getChildView(...)` and replace it with "null". It's really GC-unfriendly but... what else to do.

I'll investigate it soon to do it in more efficient way.

UPDATE:
So i figured it in some other way. I created field containing selected checkboxes. Then I `setTag(...)` to Views with checkboxes same as I save to field.