# Checkbox in GroupView in ExpandableList

Tags: android, checkbox

**My Scenario:**

I have a list in groupView and childView of Expandable list. GroupView and ChildView has checkboxes. I have no problem setting the checkboxes. I want to check all the checkboxes of ChilView when the checkbox in GroupView is checked.

I have gone through these two solutions:

[Android ExpandableListView CheckBox Select Only Clicked Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420168/android-expandablelistview-checkbox-select-only-clicked-checkbox)

and

[Check all checkbox in ExpandableListView (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215243/check-all-checkbox-in-expandablelistview-android)

I check a checkbox say in groupPosition 2 then the checkbox in say groupPosition 5 automatically gets checked.  Again when I check a checkbox say in groupPosition 1 then the checkbox in say groupPosition 6 automatically gets checked. I have saved the states of checkbox in Hash Map. Can anybody explain why is this happening.

My Code For childrenView are as follows

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final ChildHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
        holder = new ChildHolder();
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Item item = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    holder.title.setText(item.name);
    if (DataHolder.selectedGroupMembers.containsKey(groupPosition) == true)
        holder.cb.setChecked(true);
    else {
        holder.cb.setChecked(false);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

My Code for groupView are as follows

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final GroupHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);
        holder = new GroupHolder();
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.label_indicator);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (GroupHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.imageView
            .setImageResource(groupStatus[groupPosition] == 0 ? R.drawable.group_down
                    : R.drawable.group_up);
    Item groupItem = getGroup(groupPosition);

    holder.title.setText(groupItem.name);

    if (DataHolder.selectedGroupMembers.containsKey(groupPosition) == true) {
        holder.cb.setChecked(true);

    } else {
        holder.cb.setChecked(false);

    }


    holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked == true) {
                DataHolder.selectedGroupMembers.put(groupPosition,
                        new Boolean(true));
                Log.i("Prativa Clicked", "group" + groupPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else if (DataHolder.selectedGroupMembers
                    .containsKey(groupPosition)) {
                DataHolder.selectedGroupMembers.remove(groupPosition);
                Log.i("Prativa Removed ", "group" + groupPosition);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}
```

I have saved the states of hash map as follows

```
    public static HashMap<Integer,Boolean> selectedGroupMembers =     new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
```

Comment: Posting your code helps a lot.

Comment: @Prativa what is DataHolder here. its a string or object

Comment: It is a static class which holds the data used throughout the application.

Comment: hi Prativa.. i have 1 question.. if the 0th group is selected so all the child are selected. IF I **UNCHECK** THE 1 CHILD (OUT OF 10 CHILD inside 0th group) GROUP MUST GET UNCHECK. hOW TO DO IT PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence I found out the solution. The complete solution is integrated in the question itself as a final edit

Comment: hi.. prativa... you have solve this issue..? Please explain in briefly so i can implement because i have same problem..

Comment: @Sulabh Gajjar, I have edited the question to include the solution.